# "mes":"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')" when want to show value which is true in view with checkbox

Tags: asp.net-core, model, controller, action, razor-pages

Hi I have 3 tables: Role , Permission , RolePermission
In my Razor page view I want to show each permission that is true for a special role with marking the check box  . In every role I show all permission  in a tree model  (my permission is a parent child table)
So for this reason I make a model

```
           [Table("tblPermission", Schema = "cmn")]
            public class Permission
            {
          [Key]
             public int PermissionId { get; set; }
             public string PermissionTitle { get; set; }
            public int? ParentId { get; set; }

           [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
           public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
           public List<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; set; }
           }
```

And two action

```
  [BindProperty]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        Role = _permissionService.GetRoleById(id);
       var b= _permissionService.GetAllPermission();
        ViewData["Permissions"] = b;
       
        var a= _permissionService.permissionsRole(id);
        ViewData["SelectedPermission"] = a;
    }


    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        _permissionService.UpdateRole(Role);
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
```

And my view is like bellow :

```
 @page "{id}"
 @using Entities.Permission
 @model Pages.Admin.Roles.EditRoleModel
 @{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Edit role";
   List<Permission> permissions = ViewData["Permissions"] as List<Permission>;
   List<int> SelectedPermissions = ViewData["SelectedPermissions"] as List<int>;
  }

<div class="panel-body">
   <ul>
     @foreach (var permission in permissions.Where(p => p.ParentId == null))
       {
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedPermission" 
@((SelectedPermissions.Any(p=>p==permission.PermissionId)?"checked":"")) 
value="@permission.PermissionId" /> @permission.PermissionTitle
 @if (permissions.Any(p => p.ParentId == permission.ParentId))
{
<ul>
@foreach (var sub in permissions.Where(p => p.ParentId == permission.PermissionId))
  {
    <li>
  <input type="checkbox"  name="SelectedPermission"  
 @((SelectedPermissions.Any(p=>p==sub.PermissionId)?"checked":"")) value="@sub.PermissionId" 
/> @sub.PermissionTitle
</li>
  }   
 </ul>
  }
 </li>
  }
</ul>
</div>
```

At this line “@((SelectedPermissions.Any(p=>p==sub.PermissionId)?"checked":""))”  I get the error :
"mes":"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')" .And when I Check out I found that none of my viewData is not null.

Comment: Did you check `SelectedPermissions` is `null`?  Think it is typo error, in your Controller, `ViewData["SelectedPermission"]` while in View you use `ViewData["SelectedPermissions"]`. The key for `ViewData` was unmatched, hence when you cast ViewData in View as `List<int>`, it returns null for `SelectedPermissions`.

Comment: Yes change it and it worked .